# Salesforce: What is the DMLOptions field in the sObject class?

Tags: c#, api, soap, salesforce

I'm trying to serialize an sObject to pass from a C# application to Salesforce, through SOAP API, with its DML options field set.  I need to recreate (to a certain extent) the sObject class in C#.  Does anyone know the name of the DMLOptions field?  I can't find the documentation on it.

Comment: what part of [The Manual](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_setOptions) exactly didn't answer your question?

Comment: See following : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database_dmloptions.htm

Comment: Those don't give me enough information.  I edited the question so it would be more helpful, but I am essentially recreating the class in C# and I need to know more about what the setOptions function does.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it like that in SOAP API. True, in Apex they can be properties of single sObject. But they're not real. I don't think they can be (de)serialised, they make sense only till next DML operation you're about to do. In fact if you insert a list of sObjects it often makes more sense to pass them as `Database.insert(myList, options);`

In SOAP API they're closer to Apex bulk insert than single insert; they're a property of the operation, not the object so they're passed in message header. So your C# implementation of it could make a field for them if you really need to but then you'd have to unpack it somehow and pass in header when constructing actual XML.

I don't understand why you do it by hand anyway. Why not just ask SF admin to generate a WSDL file for you in Setup -> API and consume that?

The WSDL should contain section like that:

```
<operation name="create">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="SessionHeader"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="AssignmentRuleHeader"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="MruHeader"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="AllowFieldTruncationHeader"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="DisableFeedTrackingHeader"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="StreamingEnabledHeader"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="AllOrNoneHeader"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="DuplicateRuleHeader"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="LocaleOptions"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="DebuggingHeader"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="PackageVersionHeader"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="EmailHeader"/>
<soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="DebuggingInfo"/>
<soap:header use="literal" message="tns:Header" part="LimitInfoHeader"/>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
```

That's your hint. Use `AllOrNoneHeader, AllowFieldTruncationHeader, AssignmentRuleHeader, EmailHeader, LocaleOptions` [headers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/soap_headers.htm) to replicate the functionality.

Check https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-soap-api-sample-wsdls.html for more info (search for section with "*AllOrNoneHeader gives the control to commit or roll back*")

Comment: What I'm wondering is if there's some hidden field on the contact that holds the DMLOptions.  I have the DMLOptions class created in C# (including those other classes you mentioned).  This is the missing piece of the puzzle that I'm not able to find (even in the WSDL).  I guess plan B is to send the object in the parameters of the create or update functions.

Comment: No, there's no hidden field. No, there's no 1-to-1 equivalent of Apex's `setOptions` in SOAP API. I struggle to understand what are you trying to do. You have to pass them in the header, separate from actual data, period? If you try to inject weird parameter inside the XML of a record - SF will have right to ignore it or reject the message. After all it won't follow the spec laid out in the WSDL.